# How to give project name in unicode

Tags: android

In my project I need to develop app for exotic tamil scholars. I'm using android studio. My project name should be in tamil. I searched many times but I can't find the answer. How to give project name in unicode.

Comment: Do you want your app name in unicode format ?

Comment: Inside string resources change app_name like here `<string name="app_name">Name in unicode format</string>`

Comment: Accept the answer if it was useful to you...This will help others for future reference @bhuvana

Answer (score 2):

Use Strings for it.You can Localize your **app name** and etc with your language by this methodology.You can refer here [Localization in Android](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/languages.html)

Use in `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
    <activity
    android:label="@string/name">
```

Use Strings like this in `Strings.xml`

```
<string name="name">YOUR UNICODE HERE </string>
```

And you are done...

Answer (score 1):

Find you lancher activity like this

```
     `  <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>`
```

and in your res, string.xml put your app name app_name translated in your language

Answer (score 0):

In Android Studio, right click on your `strings.xml` file and select `New -> Value Resource file`.

In the dialog box, set `File Name` as `string`. Now select `Locale` from the list on left side and click `>>`.

Select `Tamil` from the list in the middle and click `Ok`.

Now you will see a file `strings.xml (ta)` unde `strings.xml` folder. Open that file and add `<string name="app_name">Name in unicode format</string>` inside the `<resource>` tags.